# Steam account hacked!

Tags: steam

My steam account got hacked by visiting a phising website via my phone. My account details including my phone number and email account that has been linked to my steam account is changed. I have contacted steam support and provided screenshot of the message that I got in my mail regarding the changing of my account details. I have also provided them the payment details that I usually use to purchase games from steam. Can my steam account  still be recovered?

Comment: @user217796 Sorry for your loss, but you're already doing all you can by talking to Steam support.  If you had any other accounts that used the same password as Steam, I'd recommend going around and changing them all, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for steam support.

Answer (score 2):

You did the right thing in contacting Steam support.

All you can do now is continue down the support workflow with them.  Provide the Steam support team everything they ask for: Previous purchase receipts, proof of identity and so on - everything that they can use to identify you are who you say you are. Hopefully it's enough to restore your access to the account.

If and when you get the account back, I would highly recommend changing your password, adding your mobile to your account, and setting up 'Steam Guard Mobile Authentication': a 2-factor auth service for an additional layer of security. You can see instructions on how to do this [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8625-wrah-9030).

We can't offer any more advice than that I'm afraid.

Comment: Steam support replied and I got my account back and I changed the password and enabled steam guard for my account. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user217796 No worries. Glad it worked out for you :)